# Types like int, double, char, long, float all start with lowercase letter, except String type. Why?

Tags: java

I am just beginning to program in Java and I noticed that String is the only type that starts with a capital letter.

Is there a reason behind this?

Comment: You have Integer, Double, Long and Float in java.lang. They are the auto boxed versions of int, double, long and float. Unfortunately, strings are not natively implementable by a processor - only characters are - and Java chose the String object to represent it.

Comment: It's not the only type; there's Long, Integer, Short, etc. String is a class.

Comment: There is also `void`, `boolean`, `byte`, `char` and `short` types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By convention, Java types that start with an upper case are Objects, while those that start with a lower case are primitives.

A primitive cannot have a method attached to it, because there is no Object to hold the method.  Also primitives cannot be subclassed, for the same reason.

Primitives also promote, which is something that Objects cannot do, as promotion changes the effective type of a primitive in ways that are not object oriented compatible.

Answer (score 4):

`String` is an `Object` and in java it is a standard naming practice to have class name AbcDef patterned

**See**

- [Java Naming Convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java)

Answer (score 2):

Because [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is a class rest are just primitive data types and the [naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) specify that the class names have to be in PascalCase.

Also, corresponding to the primitive data types, exist the [Wrapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class) class, which provide object methods for these primitive types.

Comment: You mean PascalCase. Methods are in CamelCase.

Answer (score 1):

> All primitive types start with lower-case 
>   All Java classes start with upper case